# SQL Server 2008 Compare two different database tables for column name, data type and length

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have created two different databases `Master` and `Test`. Both of them have the same tables and columns in the beginning, but then `master` is used for some stable environment and `test` is used by me for ongoing development.

Now due to development I have changed some column's data types, added some new columns to the tables, deleted some columns, added some new tables and also deleted. Now I want to make `Master` same as `test`. I cannot drop and re-create `Master` as it contains some sensitive live data. So I need to compare each and every table of `master` with `test` along with column name, data type, constraints and length. Is there any solution?

Comment: Lots of great tools to help you do this - e.g. [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare) and [Red-Gate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145979/SQL-Server-Schema-Comparison-Tool-in-Visual-Studio

Comment: If you're using VS2010 it contains data and schema comparison too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolved it my self :

```
SELECT  
    T.[name] AS [table_name], AC.[name] AS [column_name],  
        TY.[name] AS system_data_type
FROM    [master].sys.[tables] AS T  
    INNER JOIN [master].sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id] 
    INNER JOIN [master].sys.[types] TY ON AC.[system_type_id] = TY.[system_type_id]

EXCEPT

SELECT  
    T.[name] AS [table_name], AC.[name] AS [column_name],  
        TY.[name] AS system_data_type
FROM    test.sys.[tables] AS T  
    INNER JOIN test.sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id] 
    INNER JOIN test.sys.[types] TY ON AC.[system_type_id] = TY.[system_type_id]
```

This will give you the list of Columns along with Table Name, Column Name and Data Type that is in master but not exists or different from test.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any searching?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205011/SQL-Server-Database-Comparison-Tool

Comment: Showing error in this project. `Error :An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch`.